# Is this possible that use dstat tool without Python installing on computer? if yes then how?

Tags: python, graph

As I know that for using Dstat tool there should be Python on our computer. Then I can use the output generated by dstat in our java application for generating the Graph and all.but is there any other way by which without installing Python can I use dstat's output in my Java application?